# Converting Linq to XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xslt, expression-trees

Is there a way to convert LINQ queries into XSLT? the same way LINQ can be converted to SQL?

I mean if i have a solid well defined XML(Conforms to an XSD) is there a way to compile the stuff under System.Linq.Expressions into XSLT in regard to that XML?

Thank you.

To Dimitries request I'll try to elaborate a little...  Basically I have some data in one place (it's basically to chunks of xml serializable data), and I need to process them, I need to combine and process them.

Both the incoming original data , and the output result data, are XML serializable, and conform to a well defined XSD.

I want to generate the processing logic dynamically - someplace else. And allow my user to change and play around with the processing. I can represent the processing it self easily with Expression trees. Expression trees are similar to parse trees and can capture program code. This is the way linq to SQL works it converts expression trees to SQL queries.

Since all the income data and the output are both a well defined XML I can do the transformation easily with XSLT, but I'm not familiar with XSLT enough to write a dynamic XSLT generator. So I thought I could build the transformations in C# and convert them into XSLT.... again its not general purpose C#, but probably specific queries over a well defined data provider.

For the example sake:

(Not real code)

```
var schemas = XSchemaSet.Load("a","b");
var doc = XDocument.Load("File",schemas);

var result = from node in doc.Nodes
             where node.Name == "Cats" || node.Name == "Dogs"
             select (new Node(){Name = "Animal Owner", Value = node.Owner)
var newDoc = new XDocument().AddNodes(result);
newDoc.Validate(schemas);
```

Basically I want something that will function like that... I can write that in a single linq query if I use `IQueryable.Aggregate`

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your question does not make much sense. An XSLT defines a set of transformations from one XML to another. How does that relate to LINQ. Can you give any concrete examples? Btw. If you have an XSD you can use the `xsd.exe` to generate an object model from it and use LINQ to objects over that object model. And why do you want to use XSLT anyway :-p

Comment: WHat do you mean by "LINQ can be converted to XML" are you talking about using LINq-to-XML then the LINQ is not transformed to XML but queries the XML document

Comment: @Rune FS: i meant SQL sorry... i.e. in LINQ to SQL the providers convert the Linq Expression into SQL queries.

Comment: Steven I prefer to not really have the data, I want to dynamically generate the manipulations over it.

Comment: Translate what into what? Please, be more specific. There are people like me who know well XSLT and who can help, but they don't know so well LINQ -- and your question sounds too general and vague.

Comment: edited the original post

Comment: I'm familiar with both xslt and Expression/LINQ, but I don't really see the crossover here - it isn't an "obvious" design choice, IMO. Is the xslt an essential part of your solution? or is that just a tool? If so, I strongly suspect there are other (better) ways to achieve the same end. Dynamic generation can be done for C# too. Personally, I'd be looking at a meta-programming solution here.

Comment: I see, @Hellfrost. If you provide an example of the C# code that performs a transformation, I can think of ways how to transform this C# code into XSLT -- however I don't see why it is necessary to write any C# code at all -- we can just write XSLT code.

Comment: Please provide a **_silly_** example of your XML input and your expression/LINQ trees.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to create a LINQ expression tree, convert that to XSLT and use that to transform the XML. But I don't see the need for the XSLT step: you can work with LINQ to XML directly.

Comment: svick you're right, still this is the question, whether and how is it possible to convert code to XSLT...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can [implement your own query provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee672195), which uses XSLT internally, if you can figure out how to query with XSLT.

Comment: +1 for the link. But i was more hopping for something more relevant to my question

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Linq2XML?
It operates on XDocument and XElement

or alternatively if you want people to define transforms using xlst why not just execute an xslt against the document in code?

I dont see how having a Linq2XSLT would help  solve a problem without recreating it in a different form